# Format the values in tabulator cells

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, node-red, tabulator

I am working with node-red and trying to create a table with data which I feed from SQLite. I have a column (GROUP) saved as integers (0,1,2). But I would like to show this data in a table as a string ("user", "admin", "service").
So I would like to show:  0 as "user", 1 as "admin" and 2 as "service".

Is there an easy way to do so on the frontend and without for loop?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is best done on the database (back end). You could either add another column to the existing database table or more efficiently create a new database table (groups ?) in which the group names are related to their integers then incorporate this into your sql query (e.g use JOIN but there are other ways)

Answer (score 1):

Add a [customFormatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/format#format-custom)

```
formatter:function(c, fP, onR) {
    let response = 'empty';
    switch (c.getValue()) {
        0 : response = 'user'; break;
        1 : response = 'admin'; break;
        2 : response = 'service'; break;
        default : response = 'wtf'; break;
    }
    return response;
}
```

You could also use the **lookup** default formatter

```
formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:{
    "0": "user",
    "1": "admin",
    "2": "service",
}
```